# TYPO3 Calendar plugin/extension. Which one to choose?

Tags: plugins, calendar, typo3

I have no clue about where to get started with my calendar plugin. Can you please suggest me if it's easy to create one from the scratch or use an existing one and modify it. If it's the later, which plugin would be better. The following are some key functionalities of my calendar:

- The created events should be approved by someone (maybe an authorized group or something).
- The events should be customized to be displayed only on specific pages or all the pages.
- Add media library

Now, which one would be a better idea...to start a new one..or build on an existing one ? . I'm using TYPO3 6.1.0. and extension builder for creating an extension/plugin.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The most popular calendar TYPO3 extension is cal. I think, it's the most complete one.

http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/cal

Currently on TER You could find versions which are compatible with TYPO3 CMS up to 6.2.99. You could or participate in its developement, or You could fork it, or You could be inspired by it's functionalities and make Your own.